# How to best import a US Map Schematic?

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinates, georeferencing, nad83

I would like to use the following wiki US Map schematic as a background to my map work. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Blank_US_Map.svg)
It is a .svg file, and GeoReferencer is unable to import it.

1. I convert it to it to a .tiff through cloudconvert.com
2. I successfully import to GeoReferencer
3. I pick corresponding coordinates to situate my map, and use NAD83 as reference
4. Import in QGIS

=> PROBLEM: The map I have is distorted on QGIS (flattened)

What am I doing wrong?
Should import in georeference in .svg ? (IF so what plugin to install since it is unable to import). 
Should I reference more coordinates ? (>10)
Is there a setting I am missing? 
Am I using the wrong map?

I imagine many have had to import US map schematics in their QGIS, and face the similar challenge.

Comment: You're making things harder than they have to be. In GIS, one usually gets georeferenced data (often Shapefiles) and works directly with those, reprojecting them correctly (so the states are not "flattened").

Comment: Thank you for the kind pragmatic advice. Do you know where I can find a clean US Map shapefile ? Thank you

Comment: Are you interested in the whole of the US or only the lower 48?